# Array management in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help, it's killing me.
I have this array. that it's empty, when I click a button I want to add a product. but if the product is already in the array, I want to increase it's quantity in 1 on every click.
but if the product is not inside the array, I want to add it.

here's the code.

```
addProduct(product) {
  //check if array is empty, if it is, then set the product with quantity 1
  if (this.cart.length === 0) {
    product.quantity = 1;
    this.cart.push(product);
  } else {
    //if array its not empty, check if the product is already in the array
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
      if (this.cart[i].product_id == product.product_id) {
        //if they're the same id, pop the product from the array
        // and add it again but with quantity increased by one
    
        this.cart.pop(product);
        product.quantity += 1;
        this.cart.push(product);
        break;
      } else {
        //if product is not in the array, adds it with quantity 1       
        product.quantity = 1;
        this.cart.push(product);
        break;
      }
    }
  }



Expected output:
1.- cart[{
product: "product_id": 1
quantity: 1
}]
---------clicked again-----------
2.- cart [{
product: "product_id" : 1
quantity: 2
}]
-----------clicked another product--------
3.- cart [{
product: "product_id" : 1
quantity: 2
product: "product_id": 2
quantity:1}]


actual output
1.- cart[{
product: "product_id": 1
quantity: 1
}]
---------clicked again-----------
2.- cart [{
product: "product_id" : 1
quantity: 2
}]
-----------clicked another product--------
3.- cart [{
product: "product_id" : 1
quantity: 2
product: "product_id": 2
quantity:1}]
-----------clicked another product--------
4.- cart [{
product: "product_id" : 1
quantity: 2
product: "product_id": 2
quantity:1
product: "product_id": 2
quantity:1}]

it repeats the second product on and on.
```

Comment: is the product object is: 
```
{
  product: String, 
  quantity: Number
}
```
or

```
{
  product_id: String, 
  quantity: Number
}
```
or

```
{
  product: {
      product_id: String, 
  },
  quantity: Number
}
```

your code is not clear without commas

Comment: `Array.pop` doesn't take an argument, it removes the *last element* (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). Also, you don't need to remove and re-add the product at all because *you're mutating it* (which you also probably shouldn't do)

Comment: Also, take a look at [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you don't to loop over the array.
Also also, your `else` is running on every iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if an object with the ID is already in the cart. If it is just add it, otherwise add up the quantities for the found product.

```js
class Cart{
  constructor(){
    this.products = []
  }

  addProduct(product){
    const found = this.products.find(prod => prod.product_id === product.product_id)
    if(found === undefined){
      // product was not already in the cart
      this.products.push(product)
    }
    else {
      // product was already in the cart
      found.quantity += product.quantity
    }
  }

  show(){
    // show the contents of the cart
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.products, null, 4))
  }
}

const cart = new Cart()

cart.addProduct({ product_id: 1, quantity: 1 })
cart.addProduct({ product_id: 2, quantity: 1 })
cart.addProduct({ product_id: 3, quantity: 1 })
cart.show()
cart.addProduct({ product_id: 1, quantity: 2 })
cart.show()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Using your logic but applied on my code and it worked. thanks a lot.

Code updated:
`addProduct(product) {
      const found = this.cart.find(
        (prod) => prod.product_id === product.product_id
      );
      if found === undefined) {

        producto.quantity = 1;
        this.cart.push(product);
      } else {

       found.quantity += 1;
      }

    },`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep as closely to your code as possible:

1. Check to see if the products array is empty. If it is empty add in the product with a quantity of 1.
2. If it isn't empty use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the product.
3. If it exists add one to its quantity.
4. If it doesn't exist add it to the products array with a quantity of 1.

```js
class Products {

  constructor() {
    this.products = [];
  }

  addProduct(product) {
    if (!this.products.length) {
      this.products.push({ ...product, quantity: 1 });
    } else {
      const index = this.products.findIndex(item => {
        return item.productId === product.productId;
      });
      if (index > -1) {
        ++this.products[index].quantity;
      } else {
        this.products.push({ ...product, quantity: 1 });
      }
    }
  }
  
  getProducts() {
    return this.products;
  }

}

const products = new Products();

products.addProduct({ productId: 1 });
products.addProduct({ productId: 3 });
products.addProduct({ productId: 2 });
products.addProduct({ productId: 3 });
products.addProduct({ productId: 2 });
console.log(products.getProducts());
```